# How to strip http://www. from php function leaving only .com

Tags: php

I have a coupon site that display store urls on my store pages.  What I want is for only .com at end of each store without showing http:// variations in the beginning

here is my code that displays a store url and I just want domain.com to be displayed instead of http://www.domain.com, also may show as http://domain.com

```
<p class="store-url"><a href="<?php echo $url_out; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $stores_url; ?>
```

It displays like this because of this function

```
<div class="store"> 
<?php // grab the store meta data 
$term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var('term'), get_query_var('taxonomy'));
$stores_url = esc_url(get_metadata(APP_TAX_STORE, $term->term_id, 'clpr_store_url',       true));
$dest_url = esc_url(get_metadata(APP_TAX_STORE, $term->term_id, 'clpr_store_aff_url',     true));

// if there's a store aff link, then cloak it. else use store url
if ($dest_url)
$url_out = esc_url(home_url(CLPR_STORE_REDIRECT_BASE_URL . $term->slug));
else
$url_out = $stores_url; 

?>
```

What can be done................

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty - to demonstrate the possible functions...

```
<?php
function cleanInputString($inputString) {
    // lower chars
    $inputString = strtolower($inputString);

    // remove whitespaces
    $inputString = str_replace(' ', '', $inputString);

    // check for .com at the end or add otherwise
    if(substr($inputString, -4) == '.com') {
        return $inputString;
    } else {
        return $inputString .'.com';
    }
}

// example
$inputStrings = array(
 'xyzexamp.com',
 'xyzexamp',
 'xyz examp'
);

foreach($inputStrings as $string) {
    echo('input: '. $string .'; output: '. cleanInputString($string) .'<br />');
}
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
input: xyzexamp.com; output: xyzexamp.com
input: xyzexamp; output: xyzexamp.com
input: xyz examp; output: xyzexamp.com
```

Comment: I resubmitted question with more details

Answer (score 0):

The "right way" is probably to use the PHP URL-processing:

1. Break the URL up using http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php
2. Remove the scheme element of the resulting array using unset
3. Build it again using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php

Comment: `parse_url` is a great idea, but you still need to strip the leading `www.` if it is present, and it doesn't look like the author wants anything but the **PHP_URL_HOST** from the parsed url.

Answer (score 0):

This is what [**preg_replace**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) was made for:

`<?php
$http_url = 'http://www.somestore.com/some/path/to/a/page.aspx';
$domain = preg_replace('#^https?://(?:www\.)?(.*?)(?:/.*)$#', '$1', $http_url);
print $domain;
?>`

This code will print out

`somestore.com`

Comment: thanks, according to my code, how do I implement, here is what generates link..........<p class="store-url"><a href="<?php echo $url_out; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $stores_url; ?>